How to trigger multiple journeys from a single automation in SFMC?
I'm looking for a reliable way to send emails to different groups of recipients hourly. Initially, I planned to handle this via SQL queries + Send Email activity in Automation Studio. However, I'm worried that sometimes the Data Extensions will be empty, and sending emails to empty DEs might create unnecessary load in SFMC.
It seems like using Journey Builder with a Data Extension as the entry source might be a better option. If the DE is empty, no contacts would enter the journey, and no email sends would be triggered at all, which feels cleaner and avoids system overhead.
I know that we can combine Automation Studio with Journey Builder and trigger the journey directly after the SQL query via automation, but here's my challenge: automations are counted against our licensing limit and can get costly. I don't want to set up a separate automation for each group of recipients on an hourly schedule.
So, my question is: Is it possible to trigger multiple journeys from a single automation without using the API entry event (to avoid the additional credit usage tied to API calls)? Is there a script or method that can handle this?
The only approach I can think of so far is having all the SQL queries in one hourly automation, then setting the journeys to run every half-hour, with their Data Extensions populated by the SQL queries. But is there a more efficient solution?
